# A little question about tag questions

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, tag-questions

Yesterday, when I talked with my friends in English, I found a slightly odd sentence in the conversation.

> Me: What is your idea about what restaurant we should go for dinner in this shopping street？
>
> Tom：I think McDonald's is the best choice, isn't it？

In effect, I have never seen the subject of the independent sentence not as the same as the pronoun in tag questions, but I'm not sure whether his tag question is wrong. After all, his usage seems to have some logic…

So, can I use the sentence like his？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

A tag question in effect asks whether the hearer agrees with the proposition it's attached to. In this context it would be very odd to ask whether you agree with the proposition in the matrix clause, "I think X" (surely I am the only person entitled to an opinion about what I think!), but it is entirely reasonable to ask whether you agree with the proposition "X".

Paraphrase:

> I think McDonald's is the best choice—do you agree that McDonald's is the best choice?

Comment: To sum up, I can use such a tag question even though the pronoun in it is  the subject in that-clause. All I should be careful with is whether tag questions match proposition in the matrix sentence,  right? And, your edition is more normal to me hahaha～

Comment: @Changyo I'm afraid I've confused you ... the matrix clause is the main clause. What you have to be careful of is that the tag question reflects whichever clause you're asking about.